# If all of a specific PHP array element are null, don't display table column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array of client data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [client_id] => 3680
            [firstname] => Brian
            [surname] => May
            [company] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [client_id] => 3688
            [firstname] => Freddie
            [surname] => Mercury
            [company] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [client_id] => 3694
            [firstname] => Roger
            [surname] => Taylor
            [company] => 
        )
)
```

I want to display this in a table however if any element is null in ALL cases (such as "company" in this example) I don't want to show that column in the table.

Can anyone suggest how this may be done without first looping through the whole array?

Comment: Why don't you want to run through the array. It is not uncommon to prepare data for displaying in this way. The cost of doing this is much smaller than the time it takes for the browser to download and display the table. If you want only one iteration over the data - the one that builds the rows - you could javascript to remove the column client-side.

Comment: It just seems inefficient to loop through the array logging which fields are null and then loop through it again to display the data.

Comment: I don't think the alternatives are less expensive. The alternatives being some post processing either server-side (e.g. simplexml) or client-side (e.g. jQuery). A `null` comparison in a small array is very inexpensive even compared to the alternatives. You could try to make a benchmark and use this to answer your own question.

Comment: Not that the post-processing is simply a second more expensive iteration on a less accessible format.

Comment: Just do the looping, you need to it one way or another.

Comment: That looks likely. I was just wondering if there was another way but I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant avoid doing loopings in this case, so the best approach I can think about your case is:

```
<?php

$test = array
            (
        array
        (
            client_id => 3680,
            firstname => 'Brian',
            surname => 'May',
            company => null
        ),

        array
        (
            client_id => 3688,
            firstname => 'FreddieFreddie',
            surname => 'Mercury',
            company => null
        ),

        array
        (
            client_id => 3694,
            firstname => 'Roger',
            surname => 'Taylor',
            company => null
        )
);

$empty_columns = false;
foreach ($test as $item) {
    $keys = array_keys($item, null, true);

    if (count($keys) == 0)
    {
        $empty_columns = null;
        break;
    }

    if ($empty_columns===false)
        $empty_columns = $keys;

    $empty_columns= array_intersect($empty_columns, $keys); 
}
print_r($empty_columns);        
?>
```

The $empty_columns will return one array with the columns where all the values are NULL;
In this example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => company
)
```

Just check this array before print your columns.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly and I think is the best way to do this as it seems a single iteration isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$array = array(
        array('client_id' => 3680,'firstname' => 'Brian','surname' => 'May','company' => NULL),
        array('client_id' => 3688,'firstname' => 'Freddie','surname' => 'Mercury','company' => ''),
        array('client_id' => 3694,'firstname' => 'Roger','surname' => 'Taylor','company' => 'Hello World'));

print("<table>");
foreach ( $array as $list ) {
    print("<tr>");
    $col = array();
    foreach ( $list as $value ) {
        empty($value) or $col[] = $value;
    }

    if (count($col) != count($list)) {
        $ele = array_pop($col);
        foreach ( $col as $td ) {
            printf("<td>%s</td>", $td);
        }
        printf("<td colspan=\"2\">%s</td>", $ele);
    } else {
        foreach ( $col as $td ) {
            printf("<td>%s</td>", $td);
        }
    }
    print("</tr>");
}
print("</table>");
```

Output

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>3680</td>
      <td>Brian</td>
      <td colspan="2">May</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3688</td>
      <td>Freddie</td>
      <td colspan="2">Mercury</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3694</td>
      <td>Roger</td>
      <td>Taylor</td>
      <td>Hello World</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This will produce skewed rows in case the column is not entirely empty.

Comment: @Michael only worked with the example the OP give .. this is out scope but included it in the edit ... Thanks

Comment: Because he states that "company" is only an example. I can see that you updated the example, but before this updated the answer was actually wrong since he only wanted one iteration. Although provide a solution with only one iteration, he would be better of with a simpler (theoretically) less efficient solution, that is easier to read and maintain. (IMO)

Comment: Btw -- I was the downvoter, removing it since you updated the answer ;)

Comment: @Michael was only following the OP example ... but thanks for removing the downvote

Answer (score -1):

$array >> your array

```
foreach($array as $arr){

    if( !empty($arr['client_id']) &&  !empty($arr['firstname']) && !empty($arr['surname']) &   !empty($arr['company']) ){

        //show that column

    }else{

        //Don't show

    }

}
```

Comment: see comments on Hashem answer

Answer (score -1):

code to check for all nulls

```
$company=1;
foreach($yoyrary as $ary)
{
  if($ary[company]==null)
  {
   $company++
  }
}
```

now code to for display table

```
    <table>
    <th>client_id</th>
<th>firstname</th>
<th>surname</th>
<?php if($company!=count($yourary)){?><th>company</th><?php }?>
    foreach($yoyrary as $ary)
    {
     <td>client_id data</td>
<td>firstname data</td>
<td>surname data</td>
<?php if($company!=count($yourary)){?><td>company data</td><?php }?>
    }?>
    </table>
```

Comment: This is more than one iteration

Comment: That is fine for just checking one field (company). I need to check all fields as potentially any one of them could be all null.